# how to render javascript source code in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

I want to render some javascript snippet with sapui5. I am trying to use Text control but when I use that I cannt format javascript text to show up properly.Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML core control to embed html/javascript: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.HTML.html

Or create a custom control

All other SAPUI5 controls are protected against XSS and forgery attacks so they won't accept any javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest that you use `sap.ui.core.HTML` to embed HTML in your sapui5 view. However to get your code formatted correctly (for example it shall be indented correctly) you can use the [markdown-js](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js/releases) library. See this example:

## index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Render javascript source code in sapui5</title>
    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons"></script>
    <script src="markdown.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.get("markdown.md", function(data) {
            var mdView = new sap.ui.core.HTML({
                content: markdown.toHTML(data)
            });
            mdView.placeAt("uiArea");
        }, "html");
     </script>

</head>
<body class="sapUiBody">
    <div id="uiArea"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

## markdown.md:

```
# Markdown

To produce a code block in Markdown, simply indent every line of the block by at least 4 spaces or 1 tab.

    for (i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (true) {
            console.log("Hello World!");
        }
    }
```

If you want to test this example in you Chrome browser, do the following:

1. Download `markdown-browser-*.tgz` from [markdown-js](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js/releases) and place the contained `markdown.js` together with the above `index.html` and `markdown.md` in some folder.
2. Start Chrome with parameter `--allow-file-access-from-files` and drop the `index.html` on the Chrome browser window.